# Having trouble deserializing json to C#

Tags: c#, json

I have an example of what I'm trying to deserialize below and I'm getting a bunch of different errors when I try to pull the data. All I want is to pull the id value but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
{"object":"payments","entry":[{"id":"546787862118679","time":1417135022,"changed_fields":["actions"]}]}

    public class Entry
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int time { get; set; }
        public List<string> changed_fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string @object { get; set; }
        public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
    }

    dynamic result = new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
    string paymentID = items.entry.FirstorDefault().id;
```

Returns this error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault()'

Comment: try adding `using System.Linq;` to top of the file.

Comment: @ErikPhilips It is already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at the error you get, it occurs on this line:

```
string paymentID = items.entry.FirstorDefault().id; //should be .FirstOrDefault().id;
```

...to enumerate through each `Entry` item in `items.entry` which is a `List<Entry>`:

```
if (items.entry != null && items.entry.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(Entry entryItem in items.entry)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entryItem.id))
        {
            string paymentID = entryItem.id;
        }
    }
}
```

...to only access the first `Entry` item:

```
if (items.entry != null && items.entry.Count > 0)
{        
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(items.entry[0].id))
    {
        string paymentID = items.entry[0].id;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HomeworkHelpers.RTUSubscriptionActionFilter.Entry>' does not contain a definition for 'id'

Comment: see my updated answer. you're trying to access `List<Entry>.id` which doesn't make sense, you need to access the `id` property of each individual `Entry` object in `List<Entry>` instead

Comment: the json string is always the exact same. There is only one entry object so still use the same code?

Comment: yes, if there's only one `Entry` object then `List<Entry>` will only contain one item so the `foreach` loop will only execute once

Comment: @user3610374 please consider removing the downvote from my answer as well

Comment: @trashr0x I never gave you a downvote so I'm not sure what you are talking about

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling it would work if your code:

```
string paymentID = items.entry.FirstorDefault().id;
```

were

```
string paymentID = items.entry.FirstOrDefault().id;
```

And that your error is actually

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'FirstorDefault'
```

As Collections.Generic.List *does* contain a definition for `FirstOrDefault` (`System.Linq`)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
string paymentID = (items.entry.FirstOrDefault()).id;
```

Get the first item from list `entry` and then get `id`from that item.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try this: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HomeworkHelpers.RTUSubscriptionActionFilter.Entry>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstorDefault'

Comment: see this `FirstorDefault()` works with collection. this `entry` is a list or collection right ?

Comment: @RohitGupta there's a typo in your answer, it should be `FirstOrDefault` (capital O)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you loading the result into a dynamic type??? Use a string.

```
void Main()
{
    string json = @"{""object"":""payments"",""entry"":[{""id"":""546787862118679"",""time"":1417135022,""changed_fields"":[""actions""]}]}";

    Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

    Entry entry = root.Entry.FirstOrDefault();
}


public class Entry
{

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public int Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("changed_fields")]
    public string[] ChangedFields { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{

    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public string Object { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("entry")]
    public Entry[] Entry { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try this: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Answer (score 1):

For some reason (I still don't know why), your code works when you change the type of result from dynamic to string.

```
string result = new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result)) {
    var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
    string paymentID = items.entry.FirstorDefault().id;
}
```

Comment: `FirstorDefault` should be `FirstOrDefault` else you'll get `System.Collections.Generic.List<Ent‌​ry>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstorDefault'`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
string paymentID = (items.entry as List<Entry>).FirstOrDefault().id;
```